# jQuery cycle floats on top of other content

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

I tried to replace my Flash video with a jQuery cycle.  The cycle works, but the images will not stay in the editable region I placed them in.  Instead they are floating on top of other content.  Any ideas?

This is happening on the home page of massageeducator.com

There are 2 cycles on the page.  “Slideshow1” and “slideshow2”.  “slideshow1” works perfectly.

The only thing I did differently was set up “slideshow2” as a library item since it will appear on every page, but added function code manually. I tried adding code and images via the template and had the same issue.

I also tried adding both the function code and slideshow to each page instead of library item - same problem.

I have both slide shows pointing to the same `jquery.cycle.lite.1.0.js`. Should I rename this .js file and have each cycle point to a different file?

I am new to jQuery so any help is appreciated.

I can't seem to post my code due to the spam filters in here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your CSS:

```
#slideshow2 { height: 245px; }
```